# Is there an if statement to autopopulate cells in table, if checkbox checked - auto input date - then click submit to end code to table

Tags: php, html

I am working on adding an interactive table to be used by my varying teams. They want to be able to add certifications and certification dates to employs on a user information page on our internal website. The idea would be to scroll down and either check box which certs, auto populating today's date or to be able to select the date from a calendar and check box the certificate with it.

I have added been able to make the table rows with the certifications I want, date picker with calendar, and an add certification button. I haven't found anything explaining how to tie the cells together.

```html
<div id="certs" class="RoundBox InfoBox">
   <table class='DataTable'>
      <thead>
         <tr><th> Certs</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td> Cert 1</td
           <td><input type="checkbox" name="Cert1"
           <?php if (isset($Cert1) && $Cert1=="Cert1") echo "checked";?> 
            value="Cert1">Cert1</td>
           <?php echo "<td><input value=".date('Y-m-d');?>
            name="CertDate1" onclick="displayDatePicker("CertDate1" , 
            false, 'ymd', '-');" readonly />
           <input type='button' value='Date" class='btn'
            onclick="displayDatePicker("CertDate1", false, 'tmd', '-');"/>
           </td>
           <td><input type="submit" name="submitCert" 
            value="Add Certification" id="submitbutton" class="btn" />
       </tbody>
    </table
</div>
```

I have a checkbox, a submit button and date picker but they aren't working together. I am unsure if my method of making the table doesnt allow for me to link the cells together and I need to use something else to handle this or if there is a command I need to use with html. This is my first go doing things in html and I am reworking my organizations internal web page on my own (doing it on our test site prior to main site). Thanks

Comment: I'm unclear on what the problem you're trying to solve is. Can you elaborate a little more on that?

Comment: It sounds like this may be a JS/HTML issue rather than PHP/HTML. Could you clarify if something _server-side_ isn't working (ex: data is submitting as you'd expect, but is failing to insert/update in the DB) or if this is a _client-side/frontend_ issue (ex: the datepicker isn't setting the correct value on the input)

Comment: I want the date and checkbox to be linked. If you input a date, it should checkbox the cert. If you check the box then automatically add the date. I wanted to get the two linked up before working the submit button. The end goal the submit button will add the cert and date to the user's table on php. I am just trying to get the check box and date to be user friendlyish.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is just need 2 `eventListeners`. 1 for listening to checkbox `change`, and if that changes then you'll set the date field in JS. And 1 for listening to the date field in JS, and if that changes then you'll check the checkbox. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change (or http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#on) for more info on setting up eventListeners in JS

Comment: Yeah I think that's gonna do what I need it to. I will play with the listeners and reach back out if I have issues.